# Is there any way to make a JSP print carriage returns (CR)?

Tags: java, jsp, newline, vcf-vcard

I'm currently generating some vCards using JSP. I found out some platforms don't recognize these generated vCards unless their lines are separated by Carriage Returns (**CR**), and JSP seems to use just Line Feed (**LF**) by default to separate lines.

Do you guys know any way to tell the JSP to include a CR between each line?

I hope someone has a clue, cause I haven't found much out there...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to emit non-HTML format, then you should be using a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) instead of a JSP. This way you're not dependent on the JspServlet and/or appserver specifics how the output is been generated. More than often you simply cannot control this.

Using a servlet is relatively simple. Create a class which `extends HttpServlet` and implement the `doGet()` method like follows:

```
response.setContentType("text/x-vcard");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("BEGIN:VCARD" + (char) 10);
// ...
```

Map this in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/vcard/*` or `*.vcf` or whatever and use the request servletpath/pathinfo/params to generate output dynamically based on the URL.